# froyo's universal rotation and my landscape only app

Tags: android, rotation, manifest

My app is set in landscape only mode thanks to an attribute in my manifest file, but with froyo came universal rotation and a problem. It will force the screen to landscape but if the user is holding the phone upside down my app will appear upside down. Is there a way for me to set my app to only rotate when the user has their phone orientented in both landscape positions?

Answer (score 0):

I have one app in landscape mode and put in manifest this attribute:

android:screenOrientation="landscape"

Put this into activity and works fine for me (Froyo 2.2 Nexus One)

... By the way sorry for my english